# Misuse of a tag: when new users aren't sure, and experienced users don't notice

Tags: discussion, tags

**Edit:** As paxdiablo notes, I either overlooked the tag description, or it was recently edited.  But there's still a problem, and I'm not sure how the community deals with this kind of thing.

Android newbies using Android Studio often tag their questions with [android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio) even though their questions have absolutely nothing to do with which IDE they're using.  This makes it difficult to find questions that *are* about Android Studio.  As an experienced Android developer making the leap from Eclipse, I'd like to browse questions about Android Studio and find out what I don't know that I don't know.  But this is made difficult by rampant misuse of this tag.

Now, I could go around untagging questions that I think misuse the tag.  But as a brand new Android Studio user, unless the question is strictly about the Java or Android API, I'm not always certain that it's *not* related to some quirk of the IDE.  Meanwhile, experienced users probably don't notice the misuse of the tag.

So what should I do - leave a comment whenever I think the tag is being misused?

Comment: Unless the tag was edited very recently, you appear to be mistaken: `Android Studio is an official IDE targeted at Android development, based on IntelliJ IDEA from JetBrains. Please use this tag for questions related to using the IDE. Use the *android* tag for general Android development questions.` I've just updated it to say "***ONLY*** for the IDE", hopefully that will help.

Comment: That's assuming, of course, anyone even *reads* the tag info, by no means guaranteed :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Indeed.  I edited my question.

Comment: Treat it as if the question is tagged with [tag:eclipse]. If the core issue doesn't have anything to do with the IDE, just remove the tag. If you're unsure, leave it and move on (but usually it's obvious for IDE related issue). You could try to leave a comment, and *hopefully* they understand and confirm/remove it.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256114/213575) cc @paxdiablo

Comment: See also: the [tag:processing] tag.

Comment: @paxdiablo: From the number of questions about `unity3d` that are incorrectly tagged `unity`, I'd say (almost) nobody reads them.

Comment: @MattBurland Oh, no, people do read them. It's just hard to tell because those people tend to tag their questions correctly. :)

Comment: @MattBurland That one really grinds my gears - same with when people use tags where the only description is "Ambiguous - do not use". But hey, users usually figure it out after the first time their question gets edited. =P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As long as the information is still in the body of the question, the tag can usually be safely edited out. The default for almost all tags should be to assume that it's *not* relevant, and only allow its presence if it in fact turns out highly likely to be. And in [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), "the asker of the question thought it was relevant" is an *excellent* signal that it probably is no such thing*.

The exception is for language tags, where it's acceptable (and indeed recommended) to leave the tag in for any question that is not specifically language-agnostic. This serves two purposes: it allows those generally competent in most areas of a language (i.e., a large proportion of actual programmers in a given language) to easily address any questions that show up, and it allows [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), and [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions** to be asked without the asker drawing a blank and having to select a random unrelated tag in order to have something to put in that field. (This latter purpose may or may not be considered desirable by all answerers on SO, of course. But them's the breaks.)

[android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-studio), like [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode) and friends, is not a language tag, and no one cares what IDE you're using in the majority of cases, so putting that tag in is just clutter for the relatively few far more interesting questions that actually *are* about IDE functionality. (And aren't about mismatched Android SDK versions, of course.)

<sub>**There is no hyperbole in this post.*</sub>
<sub>***No, none at all, nor gentle jabs at easy targets either.*</sub>

Comment: ***Not LMAO.  At all.